# Spring boot not mapping JSP pages Intellj

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to map index1.jsp from controller.

Here is my controller method code:

```
    @GetMapping({"/", "/hello"})
public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "index1";
}
```

This is **WebConfiguration**:

```
    @Configuration
public class WebConfiguration   implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver
                = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

This is **index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Hello ${name}!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is **application.properties**:

```
spring.application.name=quiz
server.port=8090
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>quiz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>quiz</name>
    <description>Quiz app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am getting error:  **HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error**

This is from console:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index1], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
...
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index1], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I think it look up at templates folder, and not in WEB-INF/jsp. If I try to map html file from templates it works. But with JSP makes problem.

Here it is a structure of application:

[Link of picture of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhJAg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following steps you need to follow if you want to work with Spring boot + JSP instead of thymeleaf.

1. Remove thymeleaf dependency from pom.xml
2. Add below dependencies in pom.xml (Jasper to compile JSPs)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Refer https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/ for more information.

Comment: I get following errors when mouse over javax.servlet, jstl and tomcat-embed-jasper:

Dependency 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2' not found

Dependency 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.41' not found

Comment: Build the project again or update project